# How to create images with dynamic text php

Tags: php, image, text

I need to create images dynamically, i.e the text on the image will be dynamic. Is there any way to generate the images with dynamic text and save it?
I have tried the following

```
<?php

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
$imgPath = 'image.jpg';
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgPath);
$color = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
$string = "THIS TEXT IS DYNAMIC";
$fontSize = 3;
$x = 115;
$y = 185;
imagestring($image, $fontSize, $x, $y, $string, $color);
imagejpeg($image);
?>
```

but it shows me the image with the text, but it does not save the image with this text written on it. I need to save the image with the text written on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the function signature

```
bool imagejpeg ( resource $image [, string $filename [, int $quality ]] )
```

you need to set a path to a file using the second parameter.

Do it like this:

```
$saveToPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/imageCache/myImageFile.jpg';
imagejpeg( $image, $saveToPath );

header( 'Content-Type: image/jpeg' );
readfile( $saveToPath );
```

Comment: it shows me `cannot display because it contains errors`

Comment: still the same, can you please change in my code. i don't know in which line i have to add this code